# css trick for pictures slider

Tags: html, css

I need to create a pictures slider that looks like this:

[image]

The pictures need to lay one on each other on such way that the user could see the first picture on full size and some fraction form the others. Is there any way to do it on css only? Is there any available addon on the internet that give some solution for that?

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Read about css `transform` property

Comment: yes. both perspective and bootstrap-carousel gave me a full solution. thanks. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_perspective1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bootstrap-carousel` for it and `change the position and styles of the carousel indicators` by applying your custom classes to them. Here's the [link for bootstrap carousel](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/).

Comment: it is not exactly answer my question, but I think that I have found some clue - using prespective. see on that link:http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_perspective1

Comment: ya i know but if you use bootstrap-carousel along with css perspective, that solves your full question. right ?

Comment: yes. together it gives me a full solution to my problem. thank you very much Aalind Sharma:-)

Comment: @Eliran Good to know :)